# Looking for a dynamic DNS server written in Java

Tags: java, dns

I'm experimenting with an idea for a local network application that requires a dynamic DNS server that get new addresses from a database. This is only for prototyping but I need to be able to extend it using some Java logic and a SQL database. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

[DNSJava](http://www.xbill.org/dnsjava/)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using Zeroconf for this?  Allows you to easily add and remove hosts in the .local. domain.

See http://jmdns.sourceforge.net/